# connect to an sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hi new Iphone programmer here

I'm trying to connect to my sqlite database but having problems, I have the sqlite library, and the database file in my supporting files folder, it
doesn't connect when i load the simulator

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *docsDir;
        NSArray *dirPaths;

         //Get the documents directory
         dirPaths =          NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

  docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

        //Builds the path to the database file
        databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
        initWithString:[docsDir                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PetrolWatch.sqlite"]];

        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

              if([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]== YES)
              {
               lblStatus.text = @"Path Exists";

              }
              else
              {
              lblStatus.text = @"Failed to open db";
              }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the SQLite file in your documents directory, despite the fact that resources are loaded to the application bundle, then copied over to the documents directory manually.  Because I see no code that moves the file out of the bundle, perhaps `[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:]` would be a more fruitful way of checking for the existence of your file (nil path = no resource).